# Apache continually goes down (Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS - Apache 2.4.41)

Tags: apache2, crash

I hope some kind individual can help.

I'm using a Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 4 for PHP development. My development domain is regularly unreachable until I restart Apache. The /var/log/apache2/error.log file is completely empty. An Apache config test is fine.

Does anyone else know what I can check or how to debug this? I totally reinstalled the Pi and it still happens.

Comment: The error log should never be completely empty. It would have the restart messages at the very least. If the log is empty, confirm that Apache has permission to write to the log file. Also check `/var/log/syslog` for any anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting Apache to run as root:root instead of a "normal" user.